# Web application to sync data with Android phone application

Tags: php, android, html, web

I already know quite a few tricks with Android java and I have an application that I need to sync with a web application. What it needs to be doing is connect to a server and sync database and download jpg picture uploaded by user. The web application should also be for more users each with his own phone and Android application in it, so it should probably be accesable via login and password.

My problem is that I have zero experience with web applications. All I know is a little HTML. So my question is, how should I start? What language do I use? And what basic structure or principle should my web application have?
Thank you!

Comment: That's not easy to answer, but as you write you already use java, why don't you take java to create your webapplication? It's common, literature and best practices do exist, so why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a PHP - MySQL solution. PHP and MySQL are open source and I know Java can interface with that kind of database. Both languages are well documented and PHP is similar to Java in that it is C-based, so if you know Java fairly well, PHP should be relatively straightforward for you. I would recommend heading over to Lynda.com and searching for PHP Essential Training with Kevin Skoglund. Lynda is a great online video tutorial site and you can access a good amount of the content for free. But if you're serious about developing this web application, I would make the investment (I was, and I did, and I am glad). That's how I learned PHP / MySQL for the most part.

First off, to do any PHP / MySQL development, you'll need to install a server onto your computer, such as WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL PHP - for windows), MAMP (Mac " " - for mac), or LAMP (Linux " " - for Linux), where you will be able to begin developing your application. This is your "test" server, or "development" server. For instance, I use MAMP since I am on a Mac. MAMP is free, as are the other versions, but you can pay for an upgrade. For your purposes, start with the free version. Essentially, *AMP comes with the Apache Server software, MySQL database installation, and PHP installation pre-packaged and ready to go with minimal configuration. From there, you can start writing PHP and MySQL and get your project rolling.

As a matter of fact, that title at Lynda.com, PHP Essential Training, will walk you through **ALL** of the steps I just stated, AND, uses an exercise project of setting up a basic Content Management System to include password protection, user login and authentication, as well as all of the essential PHP and MySQL that you'll need to go along with it. Seriously, check out Lynda.com.

Good Luck!

Comment: Lynda.com it is than :) thank you, a friend of mine also suggested that I use PHP + mySQL but I was looking for some more ideas before I rushed into it. Anyway, thanks for giving me a heading ;)

Comment: Absolutely, I'm glad to help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open question and you might get a huge range of different answers, neither of them perfect. However, I will try to put a simple response.

Have a single server and expose from it web services. This web services will handle the CRUD of the data (I will assume you will use a database and that you have experience with databases).

Web services is a big topic. If you want the simplest web services, and you're planning to use PHP, I will suggest using RESTful with JSON, since it will be very simple.

The web application should be within the same domain/server of the web services, at least for the beginning (if it grows, you can change this architecture), since that way you won't require using JSONP and just stick to standard AJAX (I will now assume you don't know what JSONP is, I will suggest reading: http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/ which is just the first result I got on Google just now ;)) and it will be easier.

You say you have experience with Android. I will assume you know how to consume web services using Java/Android. In case you don't, here's a sample of how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Please note the PHP code there is pretty dirty, but as a "how to", I think it looks great. Only thing to note is: the sample uses HttpClient, while the preferred method is to use HttpURLConnection ( http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Having said this, PHP + MySQL is standard. In the web app, you SHOULD USE HTML. Please, don't use Flash or Java Applets (I smiled a bit by even mentioning Java Applets in here). For all the communication purposes between the web service and the HTML client, I recommend using jQuery ( http://jquery.com/ ) with AJAX.

Don't go with a JSONP API unless you want other websites to be able to use your API.

This is only a quick approach created with the little information you have given. The more (and clearer) information you give, a better solution is likely to appear.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that I provided very small amount of information, but thats just because Im a total beginner to web application development :) Ill be checking out the links you provided. I also know SQL, at least on a basic level, so that shouldnt be much of a problem. I was looking for a starting point, so thank you for it :)